# Creating grid and then plot the points on the grid in R

Tags: r, graphics

I am trying to plot somewhat complicated graph. First of all I want to create the grid and then I want to plot the variables in the grid.

To create the grid I have the coordinates of the corners of the grid. For each row I have 8 columns which represents the coordinates of the four corners. The example dataset is as follows:

```
SN  X1  Y1  X2  Y2  X3  Y3  X4  Y4
1   512398.40   3001846.80  512397.40   3002769.80  513305.40   3002770.80  513306.40   3001847.80
2   513306.40   3001847.80  513305.40   3002770.80  514213.40   3002771.80  514214.40   3001848.80
3   514214.40   3001848.80  514213.40   3002771.80  515121.50   3002772.50  515123.20   3001850.00
4   515123.20   3001850.00  515121.50   3002772.50  516030.10   3002774.00  516031.40   3001851.50
5   516031.40   3001851.50  516030.10   3002774.00  516938.40   3002775.50  516939.70   3001852.80
6   516939.70   3001852.80  516938.40   3002775.50  517846.60   3002776.80  517848.20   3001853.80
7   517848.20   3001853.80  517846.60   3002776.80  518755.20   3002778.00  518756.40   3001855.00
8   518756.40   3001855.00  518755.20   3002778.00  519663.20   3002779.50  519664.60   3001856.50
9   519664.60   3001856.50  519663.20   3002779.50  520571.60   3002781.00  520573.20   3001858.00
10  520573.20   3001858.00  520571.60   3002781.00  521479.60   3002782.80  521481.40   3001859.80
11  521481.40   3001859.80  521479.60   3002782.80  522388.20   3002784.50  522389.60   3001861.50
12  522389.60   3001861.50  522388.20   3002784.50  523296.40   3002786.00  523298.20   3001863.00
13  523298.20   3001863.00  523296.40   3002786.00  524204.40   3002787.80  524206.40   3001864.80
14  524206.40   3001864.80  524204.40   3002787.80  525113.20   3002789.80  525114.60   3001866.80
15  525114.60   3001866.80  525113.20   3002789.80  526021.40   3002791.80  526023.40   3001868.80
16  526023.40   3001868.80  526021.40   3002791.80  526929.40   3002793.80  526931.40   3001870.80
17  526931.40   3001870.80  526929.40   3002793.80  527837.40   3002795.80  527839.60   3001872.80
18  527839.60   3001872.80  527837.40   3002795.80  528746.20   3002798.00  528748.30   3001874.80
19  513305.40   3002770.80  513304.40   3003693.80  514212.40   3003694.80  514213.40   3002771.80
20  514213.40   3002771.80  514212.40   3003694.80  515120.40   3003695.80  515121.50   3002772.50
21  515121.50   3002772.50  515120.40   3003695.80  516028.60   3003697.00  516030.10   3002774.00
22  516030.10   3002774.00  516028.60   3003697.00  516937.10   3003698.50  516938.40   3002775.50
23  516938.40   3002775.50  516937.10   3003698.50  517845.40   3003699.80  517846.60   3002776.80
24  517846.60   3002776.80  517845.40   3003699.80  518753.60   3003701.00  518755.20   3002778.00
25  518755.20   3002778.00  518753.60   3003701.00  519661.60   3003702.50  519663.20   3002779.50
26  519663.20   3002779.50  519661.60   3003702.50  520570.20   3003704.00  520571.60   3002781.00
27  520571.60   3002781.00  520570.20   3003704.00  521478.30   3003705.80  521479.60   3002782.80
28  521479.60   3002782.80  521478.30   3003705.80  522386.40   3003707.50  522388.20   3002784.50
29  522388.20   3002784.50  522386.40   3003707.50  523294.40   3003709.00  523296.40   3002786.00
30  523296.40   3002786.00  523294.40   3003709.00  524202.60   3003710.80  524204.40   3002787.80
31  524204.40   3002787.80  524202.60   3003710.80  525111.40   3003712.80  525113.20   3002789.80
32  525113.20   3002789.80  525111.40   3003712.80  526019.40   3003714.80  526021.40   3002791.80
33  526021.40   3002791.80  526019.40   3003714.80  526927.40   3003716.80  526929.40   3002793.80
34  526929.40   3002793.80  526927.40   3003716.80  527835.40   3003718.80  527837.40   3002795.80
35  527837.40   3002795.80  527835.40   3003718.80  528743.80   3003721.00  528746.20   3002798.00
36  513304.40   3003693.80  513303.40   3004616.80  514211.40   3004617.80  514212.40   3003694.80
37  514212.40   3003694.80  514211.40   3004617.80  515119.40   3004618.80  515120.40   3003695.80
38  515120.40   3003695.80  515119.40   3004618.80  516027.40   3004620.00  516028.60   3003697.00
39  516028.60   3003697.00  516027.40   3004620.00  516935.60   3004621.50  516937.10   3003698.50
40  516937.10   3003698.50  516935.60   3004621.50  517844.20   3004622.80  517845.40   3003699.80
41  517845.40   3003699.80  517844.20   3004622.80  518752.30   3004624.00  518753.60   3003701.00
42  518753.60   3003701.00  518752.30   3004624.00  519660.30   3004625.50  519661.60   3003702.50
43  519661.60   3003702.50  519660.30   3004625.50  520568.40   3004627.00  520570.20   3003704.00
44  520570.20   3003704.00  520568.40   3004627.00  521476.30   3004629.00  521478.30   3003705.80
45  521478.30   3003705.80  521476.30   3004629.00  522384.60   3004630.50  522386.40   3003707.50
46  522386.40   3003707.50  522384.60   3004630.50  523292.60   3004632.00  523294.40   3003709.00
47  523294.40   3003709.00  523292.60   3004632.00  524201.20   3004633.80  524202.60   3003710.80
48  524202.60   3003710.80  524201.20   3004633.80  525109.40   3004635.80  525111.40   3003712.80
49  525111.40   3003712.80  525109.40   3004635.80  526017.40   3004637.80  526019.40   3003714.80
50  526019.40   3003714.80  526017.40   3004637.80  526925.40   3004639.80  526927.40   3003716.80
51  526927.40   3003716.80  526925.40   3004639.80  527833.40   3004641.80  527835.40   3003718.80
52  515119.40   3004618.80  515118.40   3005541.80  516026.40   3005543.00  516027.40   3004620.00
53  516027.40   3004620.00  516026.40   3005543.00  516934.40   3005544.50  516935.60   3004621.50
54  516935.60   3004621.50  516934.40   3005544.50  517842.50   3005545.80  517844.20   3004622.80
55  517844.20   3004622.80  517842.50   3005545.80  518750.50   3005547.00  518752.30   3004624.00
56  518752.30   3004624.00  518750.50   3005547.00  519658.50   3005548.50  519660.30   3004625.50
57  519660.30   3004625.50  519658.50   3005548.50  520566.50   3005550.00  520568.40   3004627.00
58  520568.40   3004627.00  520566.50   3005550.00  521474.60   3005551.50  521476.30   3004629.00
59  521476.30   3004629.00  521474.60   3005551.50  522383.20   3005553.00  522384.60   3004630.50
60  522384.60   3004630.50  522383.20   3005553.00  523291.30   3005554.80  523292.60   3004632.00
61  523292.60   3004632.00  523291.30   3005554.80  524199.40   3005556.80  524201.20   3004633.80
62  524201.20   3004633.80  524199.40   3005556.80  525107.40   3005558.80  525109.40   3004635.80
63  525109.40   3004635.80  525107.40   3005558.80  526015.40   3005560.80  526017.40   3004637.80
64  526017.40   3004637.80  526015.40   3005560.80  526923.40   3005562.80  526925.40   3004639.80
65  515118.40   3005541.80  515117.40   3006464.80  516025.50   3006466.00  516026.40   3005543.00
66  516026.40   3005543.00  516025.50   3006466.00  516933.30   3006467.50  516934.40   3005544.50
67  516934.40   3005544.50  516933.30   3006467.50  517841.30   3006468.80  517842.50   3005545.80
68  517842.50   3005545.80  517841.30   3006468.80  518749.30   3006470.00  518750.50   3005547.00
69  518750.50   3005547.00  518749.30   3006470.00  519657.30   3006471.50  519658.50   3005548.50
70  519658.50   3005548.50  519657.30   3006471.50  520565.30   3006473.00  520566.50   3005550.00
71  520566.50   3005550.00  520565.30   3006473.00  521473.30   3006474.50  521474.60   3005551.50
72  521474.60   3005551.50  521473.30   3006474.50  522381.40   3006476.00  522383.20   3005553.00
73  522383.20   3005553.00  522381.40   3006476.00  523289.40   3006477.80  523291.30   3005554.80
74  523291.30   3005554.80  523289.40   3006477.80  524197.40   3006479.80  524199.40   3005556.80
75  524199.40   3005556.80  524197.40   3006479.80  525105.40   3006481.80  525107.40   3005558.80
76  516025.50   3006466.00  516024.20   3007389.00  516931.60   3007390.50  516933.30   3006467.50
77  516933.30   3006467.50  516931.60   3007390.50  517839.50   3007391.80  517841.30   3006468.80
78  517841.30   3006468.80  517839.50   3007391.80  518747.50   3007393.00  518749.30   3006470.00
79  518749.30   3006470.00  518747.50   3007393.00  519655.50   3007394.50  519657.30   3006471.50
80  519657.30   3006471.50  519655.50   3007394.50  520563.50   3007396.00  520565.30   3006473.00
81  520565.30   3006473.00  520563.50   3007396.00  521471.50   3007397.50  521473.30   3006474.50
82  521473.30   3006474.50  521471.50   3007397.50  522379.30   3007399.00  522381.40   3006476.00
83  522381.40   3006476.00  522379.30   3007399.00  523287.40   3007400.80  523289.40   3006477.80
84  523289.40   3006477.80  523287.40   3007400.80  524195.40   3007402.80  524197.40   3006479.80
85  516024.20   3007389.00  516022.50   3008312.00  516930.20   3008313.50  516931.60   3007390.50
86  516931.60   3007390.50  516930.20   3008313.50  517838.40   3008314.80  517839.50   3007391.80
87  517839.50   3007391.80  517838.40   3008314.80  518746.50   3008316.00  518747.50   3007393.00
88  518747.50   3007393.00  518746.50   3008316.00  519654.30   3008317.50  519655.50   3007394.50
89  519655.50   3007394.50  519654.30   3008317.50  520562.30   3008319.00  520563.50   3007396.00
90  520563.50   3007396.00  520562.30   3008319.00  521470.30   3008320.50  521471.50   3007397.50
91  521471.50   3007397.50  521470.30   3008320.50  522377.70   3008322.00  522379.30   3007399.00
92  518746.50   3008316.00  518745.10   3009239.00  519652.60   3009240.50  519654.30   3008317.50
93  519654.30   3008317.50  519652.60   3009240.50  520560.50   3009242.00  520562.30   3008319.00
94  520562.30   3008319.00  520560.50   3009242.00  521468.40   3009243.80  521470.30   3008320.50
```

To create a grid I need to connect the four corner points of each row and then proceed to the next row. After I connect all the points on each row my grid is complete.

After the grid is complete, I want to plot the variables on the grid and the variable should fit the whole rectangle / quadrilateral of the grid. To plot the grid I have the centroid for each grid and the variable to be plotted.

```
SN  XC  YC  ELEV
1   512851.9    3002308.8   1.5
2   513759.9    3002309.8   1.5
3   513758.9    3003232.8   1.5
4   513757.9    3004155.8   1.5
5   514668.1    3002310.8   1.5
6   514666.9    3003233.7   1.5
7   514665.9    3004156.8   1.5
8   515576.6    3002312 1.573
9   515575.2    3003234.8   1.5
10  515574  3004157.9   1.5
11  515572.9    3005080.9   1.5
12  515571.9    3006003.9   1.5
13  516484.9    3002313.5   1.816
14  516483.6    3003236.3   1.524
15  516482.2    3004159.3   1.5
16  516481  3005082.3   1.5
17  516479.9    3006005.3   1.5
18  516478.7    3006928.3   1.5
19  516477.1    3007851.3   1.5
20  517393.2    3002314.7   2.122
21  517391.9    3003237.7   1.857
22  517390.6    3004160.7   1.746
23  517389.2    3005083.7   1.788
24  517387.9    3006006.7   1.778
25  517386.4    3006929.7   1.635
26  517384.9    3007852.7   1.5
27  518301.6    3002315.9   2.492
28  518300.2    3003238.9   2.309
29  518298.9    3004161.9   2.236
30  518297.4    3005084.9   2.239
31  518295.9    3006007.9   2.146
32  518294.4    3006930.9   1.887
33  518293  3007853.9   1.622
34  519209.9    3002317.3   2.831
35  519208.4    3003240.3   2.72
36  519207  3004163.3   2.64
37  519205.4    3005086.3   2.574
38  519203.9    3006009.3   2.429
39  519202.4    3006932.3   2.124
40  519201  3007855.3   1.774
41  519199.6    3008778.3   1.583
42  520118.2    3002318.8   3.079
43  520116.7    3003241.8   2.997
44  520115.1    3004164.8   2.899
45  520113.4    3005087.8   2.797
46  520111.9    3006010.8   2.634
47  520110.4    3006933.8   2.275
48  520108.9    3007856.8   1.795
49  520107.4    3008779.8   1.637
50  521026.5    3002320.4   3.244
51  521024.9    3003243.4   3.158
52  521023.3    3004166.5   3.05
53  521021.5    3005089.4   2.93
54  521019.9    3006012.3   2.723
55  521018.4    3006935.3   2.244
56  521016.9    3007858.3   1.648
57  521015.4    3008781.3   1.637
58  521934.7    3002322.2   3.348
59  521933.1    3003245.2   3.244
60  521931.4    3004168.2   3.111
61  521929.7    3005091 2.94
62  521928.1    3006013.8   2.655
63  521926.4    3006936.8   2.15
64  521924.7    3007859.8   1.5
65  522843.1    3002323.8   3.395
66  522841.4    3003246.8   3.259
67  522839.5    3004169.8   3.066
68  522837.9    3005092.6   2.799
69  522836.3    3006015.4   2.434
70  522834.4    3006938.4   2.06
71  523751.4    3002325.4   3.365
72  523749.5    3003248.4   3.179
73  523747.7    3004171.4   2.906
74  523746.1    3005094.4   2.555
75  523744.4    3006017.3   2.185
76  523742.4    3006940.3   1.851
77  524659.7    3002327.3   3.187
78  524657.9    3003250.3   2.946
79  524656.2    3004173.3   2.613
80  524654.4    3005096.3   2.284
81  524652.4    3006019.3   2
82  525568.2    3002329.3   2.834
83  525566.4    3003252.3   2.532
84  525564.4    3004175.3   2.128
85  525562.4    3005098.3   1.82
86  526476.4    3002331.3   2.343
87  526474.4    3003254.3   1.977
88  526472.4    3004177.3   1.562
89  526470.4    3005100.3   1.5
90  527384.5    3002333.3   1.753
91  527382.4    3003256.3   1.5
92  527380.4    3004179.3   1.5
93  528292.9    3002335.4   1.5
94  528290.7    3003258.4   1.5
```

IN the above dataset, ELEV is the elevation and is the variable to be plotted on the grid. So, the idea is while plotting the grid each grid should be assigned a name. So, later for plotting the variable same name / number can be referred to plot the variable.

The output I need looks like this:

[image]

Note: The grid size are constant only on this sample dataset. The dataset I am working on is very huge and contains irregular grid. **Any plotting package / solution is acceptable.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a final solution(surely half-solution) But I think it is a good start. I am using `ggplot2`. Mainly I create the grid using `geom_polygon` and fill it by adding a new layer of EELV color.

1. First of all I am reading your data. `grid.dd <- read.table(text="SN  X1  Y1  X2...",header=TRUE)` and `eelv.d <- read.table(text="SN  XC  YC  ELEV...",header=TRUE)`.
2. Then I am reshaping the data.
3. I plot the grid

Here my R code:

```
## add new id to identifiy polygon, each row is a polygon
grid.dd$id <- rownames(grid.dd)
## put the data in the long format since geom_polygon 
## needs aes(x,y,group) using reshape
dd.long <- reshape(grid.dd, dir='long', varying=list(c(1,3,5,7),
                                      c(2,4,6,8)), v.names=c('X', 'Y'),times =1:4)
## attempt to use merge but this gives a strange result
## dat <- merge(dd.long,eelv.d,by.x='id',by.y='SN')

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd.long, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes( group=factor(id)),fill='transparent',col='black')+
  geom_point(data=eelv.d,aes(x=XC,y=YC,col=ELEV),size=10)+
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for your efforts. Would you also add the code to read the data ? Right now I am confused what is grid.dd.

Comment: Is it possible to add contour lines of elevation on the above figure ?